# some sort of QR code impossible to decode?

Tags: qr-code, decoding

I recently found some sort of odd QR code. No scanner works.

I think it's from our city's transit system but no decoders work that I've tried like zxing etc...

Can anyone identify the type of barcode this is and possibly educate me on understanding the deconstruction of it thanks.

[image: the barcode]

Comment: inlined image and cleanup

Answer (score 0):

By pure luck I just found the answer. This type a QR code is use by application like Google Anthenticator (more broadly it's a virtual MFA device) to synchronise an account and your MFA app. I just used something like that to secure my AWS account ^^

[EDIT]: I forgot to say the acronym you could search is "OTP". you can also look at [this](https://freeotp.github.io/qrcode.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520928/how-to-generate-a-qr-code-for-google-authenticator-that-correctly-shows-issuer-d)